# Validation not working for file(already exist/type) while insertion of record in mysql database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my postaddata.php code:

```
require('includes/database.php');
$db = new Database();
if(isset($_POST['btnPostad']))
{
    $allowedextensions = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
    $extensions = end(explode ("." , $_FILES['file']['name']));
    if((($_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/gif')
    || ($_FILES["file"]['type'] == 'image/jpg')
    || ($_FILES["file"]['type'] == 'image/png')
    || ($_FILES["file"]['type'] == 'image/jpeg'))
    && ($_FILES["file"]['size'] > 20000)
    && (in_array($extensions, $allowedextensions)))
    {
        if($_FILES['file']['error']> 0)
        {
            $msg =  "Error: " . $_FILES['file']['error'] . "<br>";
            header('Location:postad.php?msg='.$msg);
        }
        else
        {
            $msg2 = "Upload " . $_FILES['file']['name'] . "<br>";
            $msg2 .= "Type " . $_FILES['file']['type'] . "<br>";
            $msg2 .= "Size " . ($_FILES['file']['size'] / 1024 ). "KB" . "<br>";
            $msg2 .= "Stored In " . $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] . "<br>";
            if (file_exists("uploads/". $_FILES['file']['name']))
            {
                $msg =  $_FILES['file']['name']. "already exists";
                header('Location:postad.php?msg='.$msg);
            }
            else
            {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "uploads/" . $_FILES['file']['name']);
                //$msg1 =  "Stored in uploads/: " . $_FILES['file']['name'];
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $msg =  '<b> <font face="Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif" color="red">File type is not Supported, Please try uploading recommended formats (JPG, JPEG, GIF, PNG)</font></b>';
        header('Location:postad.php?msg='.$msg);
    }
    //header('Location:postad.php?msg='.$msg1);
    $pic =  ($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $data = array
    (
    'Ad_Status' => $_POST['adstatus'],
    'Model_Year' => $_POST['model_year'],
    'Car_Make' => $_POST['car_make'],
    'Car_Model' => $_POST['car_model'],
    'City' => $_POST['city'],
    'Price' => $_POST['price'],
    'Mileage' => $_POST['mileage'],
    'Mileage_Unit' => $_POST['mileage_unit'],
    'Transmission' => $_POST['transmission'],
    'Engine_Type' => $_POST['engine_type'],
    'Engine_Capacity' => $_POST['engine_capacity'],
    'Exterior_Color' => $_POST['exterior_color'],
    'Air_Bags' => $_POST['air_bags'],
    'Air_Conditioner' => $_POST['air_conditioner'],
    'Power_Steering' => $_POST['power_steering'],
    'Power_Locks' => $_POST['power_locks'],
    'Power_Mirror' => $_POST['power_mirror'],
    'Keyless_Entry' => $_POST['keyless_entry'],
    'Cruise_Control' => $_POST['cruise_control'],
    'Navigation_System' => $_POST['navigation_system'],
    'FM_Radio' => $_POST['fm_radio'],
    'Cassette_Player' => $_POST['cassette_player'],
    'CD_Player' => $_POST['cd_player'],
    'Sun_Roof' => $_POST['sun_roof'],
    'Alloy_Rims' => $_POST['alloy_rims'],
    'HID' => $_POST['hid'],
    'Comments' => $_POST['comments'],
    'Car_Image' => $pic,
    'Display_Name' => $_POST['display_name'],
    'Email' => $_POST['email'],
    'Mobile_Number' => $_POST['mobile_number'],
    'Secondary_Number' => $_POST['secondary_number'],
    'Featured' => $_POST['featured']
    );
    $result_insert_data = $db->insert('car_information',$data);
    $msg = '<b> <font face="Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif" color="green">Your Ad has been posted and will be reviewed and displayed within 24hrs</font></b>';
    header('Location:Index.php?msg='.$msg);
}
else
{
    $msg = '<b> <font face="Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif" color="red">Your Ad has not been posted! Please, try again later</font></b>';
    header('Location:postad.php?msg='.$msg);
}
```

Validation is not working for file(already exist/type) while insertion of record in mysql database using PHP. As you can see, file functions/validation resides before posting the data into database. I want to restrict duplication image insertion/ file type restriction etc. Although I've written the code I believe there is some problem with my if/else also.  Can you help?

Comment: are you getting any error message ?

Comment: nope! it simply insert the record and not taking care of the conditions for the file mentioned before insertion!

Comment: so the database part is working correctly right ?

Comment: yes! Right! no problem at all in insetion!

Comment: where in your code are you checking for duplicate files ?

Comment: here
 if (file_exists("uploads/". $_FILES['file']['name']))
            {
                $msg =  $_FILES['file']['name']. "already exists";
                header('Location:postad.php?msg='.$msg);
            }

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [documentation for `file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) and look at some of the reasons why it might fail.

1. `file_exists` doesn't work for symlinks pointing to non-existing files. This probably isn't your issue.
2. `FALSE` is returned for files which are inaccessible because of [safe mode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php) restrictions. This probably isn't it either.
3. But next, read the note at the bottom: **The results of `file_exists` are cached.** This can cause unexpected behavior.

You'll want to try the [**`clearstatcache()` function**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php). From its documentation:

> You should also note that PHP doesn't cache information about non-existent files. So, if you call `file_exists()` on a file that doesn't exist, it will return FALSE until you create the file. If you create the file, it will return TRUE even if you then delete the file.

What you might try is calling the following function before your `if` statement:

```
clearstatcache(true, "uploads/". $_FILES['file']['name']);
if(file_exists("uploads/". $_FILES['file']['name']))
{
    // And so on...
```